# Redirect taxonomy term to query string without trailing slash

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am using a custom template to filter posts with query string and need to redirect all auto-generated URLs to that template, so that `domain.com/taxonomy/term/` should redirect to `domain.com/template/?taxonomy=term`.

This is what I have now:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/taxonomy/(.*)/?$ /template/?taxonomy=$1`

But it results in `domain.com/template/?taxonomy=term/` (with a trailing slash at the end), which breaks my filters. How to remove this trailing slash from resulting URL?

Comment: `(.*)` matches `term/` already, and the `/?` behind it then simply doesn’t match anything any more. If you want to leave the trailing slash optional, then replace this with a character class that allows everything but a slash. `(.*)` -> `([^/]*)`

Comment: I made the change but still getting the same result.

Comment: @04FS If initial URL has a trailing slash then resulting URL has it as well. Is it possible to force no slash after query?

Comment: Looks like the problem is in WordPress itself, because it works on a non-WP site.